# GitHub project is ahead of me, how to solve this with QGit

Tags: git, github

Sorry for the easy nature of this question, but I'm having difficulty finding the answer.

The project on GitHub is (ahead?) of the local version, the local version is out of date.

How can I use QGit to rectify this? I find it much less clear than on Windows with either the official GitHub app for such or Git Extensions.

Comment: Stackoverflow or Superuser may be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a `git pull`

'Pull' does not show up in [qgit's documentation](http://digilander.libero.it/mcostalba/qgit_guide.html).

Since a `git pull` is the same thing as a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` I've checked their documentation for those words.

It states:

> Actions can be added/removed using a dedicated dialog invoked from
>   Actions->Setup actions… menu. Actions can be activated clicking on
>   their name from the Actions menu.
>
> Each action can be associated to a list of any type of git or shell
>   commands or to an external script.
>
> While an action is running a terminal window is shown to display the
>   corresponding output.
>
> An action can also ask for command line arguments before to run so to
>   allow for maximum flexibility.

It looks like you need to go to Actions->Setup actions and define a fetch and merge from there.

---

It may just be easier to do this from the command line

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
git pull
```

Comment: Excellent, TY. I've added the action 'pull' that is 'cd' then 'cd path_to_git_repository' then 'git pull'.

Comment: For those who don't know what TY means ( I sure didn't )  http://www.internetslang.com/TY-meaning-definition.asp